# How to connect to an ldap server via ldapsearch?

Tags: ldap

Used

```
ldapsearch -x -b dc=domain,dc=com -H ldap://10.0.0.4
```

Issued

```
To perform this operation, you must ensure successful connection binding., data 0, v3839
```

After diving into Google, I came across the fact that it is necessary to update

```
apt install ldap-utils
```

Here it gives

```
E: Subprocess /usr/bin/dpkg returns error code (100)
```

Then I found that I need to install or update apt, but it already gives an error with dpkg not bad above. I don’t know what to do next.

Comment: Please provide clear details; which include what OS & release you're using, the command you used which you do mention (`apt install ldap-utils`) and full messages and not just the E: summary (*at the end of the list; which is intended to make you scan the lines above*). About all we can currently do is tell you to read the messages you skipped over, being limited to details you provide  (the `apt` command called `dpkg` as a subprocess which encountered the error; that's the line you need to read, not the summary detail when the subprocess returned to `apt` which you provided to us)